# Создание сайта мультивендора (marketplace) PHP и его фреймворки

Tags: php

Создавал сайт (на yope) интернет магазин, на yope и вот заказчичу понадобилось создать сайт  мультивендор, чтобы пользователи могли создавать и продавать товар сами, а платформа имела % , даже не представляю на чем можно это реализовать, (цены на мутивендорные скрипты начинаются от 300$ и доходят до 7000$)

У кого какие идеи

Comment: Что значит мультивендор? Просто множество продавцов, зареганных на сайте? Делайте на чем угодно, если это так, хоть на том же yope.

Comment: Не пойдет, он будет высоко нагруженным, (росто множество продавцов, зареганных на сайте), да и все они вытаскивают свой товар

Comment: Перед Вами стоит выбор сейчас: фреймворк, CMS или самописка, Вы должны исходить из реалий: кол-во пользователей, кол-во товаров, кол-во посещений в день. Я бы рекомендовал написать "велосипед" в связи с вопросом ТОЛЬКО будущих нагрузок, во всех остальных случаях только фреймворки.